# Getting the time part of a DateTime and feeding it to a Masked Text box

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datetime

My XAML coverter for my time field on the form return some "DateTime" object like this:

```
protected override DateTime? OnConvert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

{01/30/14 3:00:00 PM}
```

which my Telerik Timepicker will show its time part. Everything good!.
Now I also have a "Masked Text Box" on the same form that is showing the same Time as the time above. ( this one a read only one and it is a masked textbox not a DateTime pikcer control like before) so it expects "String" ... my Converter is returning "DateTime" and the mask is like **"##:## aa"**  Currently with the example DateTime above the mask is showing **"01:30 /1"**

So now I am looking for a way to: get the time part of that result and give it to MaskedTextBox so it can still display it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the Telerik RadMaskedTextBox.  In that case, you should set the MaskType property to DateTime (see http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/working_with_radmaskedtextbox.html).  The valid DateTime masks are described at http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radmaskedtextbox-features-date-time-mask.html.

Comment: it is the newer maskedinputtextbox or some name like that. Doesn't have MaskType property. Thanks

Comment: @DevWannaBe what's the fully namespace-qualified name of the type?

Comment: In the converter?  System.Type

Comment: @DevWannaBe no, of the text box class.  The only MaskedInputTextBox class I could find is an Infragistics control.

Comment: oh that should be a string I think.

Comment: No, it should be something like `Infragistics.Controls.Editors.Primitives.MaskedInputTextBox` or perhaps `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox` or `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox`.  We need to know exactly which class you're using in order to answer the question.